# How do I go about restarting slony?

Tags: postgresql, slony

One of the slaves is running behind on replication.
It is recommended that you restart slony when this happens.
What are the steps one should take to go about restarting it?

Thanks,
Sharad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how you installed Slony.  For example, if you have Debian packages, use the usual `/etc/init.d/slony1 restart`.

Comment: I didn't use the package, now what?

Comment: Then it depends on how you installed it.  You're on your own, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

You would find slony related binaries in bin directory of Postgres installation directory 
for example -> /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/slon_kill can be used

slon_kill --help

```
Usage: slon_kill [--config file] [-w|--watchdog]

    --config file  Location of the slon_tools.conf file

    -w
    --watchdog     Only kill the watchdog process(es)

    Kills all running slon and slon_watchdog on this machine for every
    node in the cluster.
```